# Determine if device can simultaneously call and stream data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cdma

My iPhone application needs to dial a phone number and send some data to a remote server.

It's important that I:

1. Trigger the call, and then
2. set up a background task that will communicate with my server

I've been developing/testing with an AT&T phone, which has no problem sending the data in the background while a phone call is initiated.

However, Verizon customers don't have the ability to call and stream data, so for them, I'd like to reverse my order of operations.

What's the best way to determine which route I need to take?  I've seen examples of looking at the iPhone's model number, and if it's 3.3, it means it's Verizon so I can proceed from there, but that doesn't seem robust or future proof. Is Verizon the only carrier that currently has this limitation?  Seems like there should be some sort of property like `-[UIDevice isMultiTaskingSupported]`.

Comment: First starting background task should work in both, yes?

Comment: not according to my beta testers.

Comment: Hmmmm because I dont know exactly how video calling works but that might be following same mechanism....and both of those company provides it yes?

Comment: AT&T phones on EDGE can't do voice and data at the same time, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no great one-liner like the `UIDevice` method you mentioned, but there is the [Core Telephony](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html) framework. I haven’t used it myself, but it seems like you could use the [`CTCarrier`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009596) class to find this out, specifically the [`mobileNetworkCode`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/mobileNetworkCode) property. [This list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_Network_Code) should get you started. From the look of it, for *some* carriers, you can use this code to determine if you’re on EDGE or not. For CDMA or EDGE networks, the answer will be “no” for simultaneously streaming voice and data, but for GSM networks that *aren’t* EDGE, you’re good. You could also just use the [`carrierName`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCarrier/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CTCarrier/carrierName) property and look for “AT&T,” but that doesn’t account for EDGE.

Is there a *good* solution? Probably not.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because I came to the same conclusion.  There's no good solution. Mixing in different carriers + whether or not a user is on EDGE is, in my opinion, too fragile to code around.  I ended up switching the 'order of operations,' even though I was really trying to avoid that.

Comment: @djibouti33: This is where I direct you to bugreport.apple.com… ;)